# 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference & <item element should not be here

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to define a button in my `Home` activity to open my `Settings` activity but I get the error :

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.example.padmw/com.example.padmw.Home}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)'
>   on a null object reference

My layout for the Settings item is in `res/menu`, I tried moving it to `res/layout` but then it says that element item should not be there. What should i do?

My Button in Home.class:

```
    Button mButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.action_settings);
    mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            startActivity(new Intent(Home.this, SettingsActivity.class));
        }
    });
```

My item in res/home.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        app:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>
```

Comment: Please use the android-studio tag only if your problem is directly related to the IDE android-studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So for the menu item, we do in this way
1) To specify the options menu for an activity, override onCreateOptionsMenu(). In this method, you can inflate your menu resource:-

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.game_menu, menu);
    return true;
}
```

2)Handling click events:
  You can match this ID against known menu items to perform the appropriate action. For example:

```
 @Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle item selection
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_settings:
          // do your work
            return true;

        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use `findViewById`, button should be in your layout, not menu.

For menu you need to override `onOptionsItemSelected`

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_settings:
            // do something
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

And you need to inflate home.xml menu :

```
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.home, menu);
        return true;
    }
```

Note that your home.xml should be in `res/menu/` folder.